# Inverse of DiracDelta at 0 is 99/5?

Tags: distributions, inverse

Here in this other [question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660297/inverse-of-diracdelta-function) I asked the question, but maybe here is more pertinent.

When using Mathematica we can find the following result:

```
InverseFunction[DiracDelta][0] == 99/5 (* returns True *)
```

Is this a bug or is it actually a real result?
If it is a valid result, how can we prove it?

Comment: Returns `False` for me.

Comment: o.O, I cleaned my Kernel before trying. Are you using 12.1?
What `InverseFunction[DiracDelta][0]` gives to you?

Comment: `v10.4` - and `InverseFunction[DiracDelta][0]` returns `42/5`. I'd call it a bug. Contact Wolfram support to ask them if they have any justification for this (although from the mathematical point of view this doesn't make sense), and report to them this is a likely bug.

Comment: Seems `InverseFunction` is making a call to `FindInstance`. This can be seen with `TracePrint[InverseFunction[DiracDelta][0], _FindInstance, 
 TraceInternal -> True]`.

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug, but next time, please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag yourself on your own questions. Let someone else who can confirm what you observe add it.

Comment: Well, `DiracDelta[99/5]` is zero, that's correct, no? :D See second point under Details on the `InverseFunction` ref page. This is kind of a GIGO situation in my opinion. What would be a valid result in your opinion?

Comment: @J.M. I disagree that this is a bug, in this case. It's an edge case where an otherwise reasonable approach taken by `InverseFunction` leads to a very strange outcome.

Comment: The $\delta$-distribution is not a usual function so `DiracDelta[99/5]` makes no sense. Therefore, the input should be returned with an error message.

Comment: Confirm it in version 12.0 on Windows 10 and 12.1 on Linux.

Comment: "an otherwise reasonable approach taken by `InverseFunction`" - my personal opinion is that `InverseFunction[]` should just refuse to work with things like `DiracDelta[]` and `HeavisideTheta[]`, @Szabolcs. I guess we will have to agree to disagree here.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree that this is a bug. From the [`InverseFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html) docs,

> As discussed in "Functions That Do Not Have Unique Values", many mathematical functions do not have unique inverses. In such cases, `InverseFunction[f]` can represent only one of the possible inverses for `f`.

Thus, `InverseFunction[f][x]` returns *some* `y` such that `f[y] == x`.

This is fine:

```
DiracDelta[99/5]
(* 0 *)
```

Another comparable example:

```
InverseFunction[UnitStep][1]
(* 0 *)

InverseFunction[UnitStep][0]
(* -1 *)
```

It seems to me that this is a [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) situation because `DiracDelta` and `UnitStep` yield the same result for infinitely many inputs. Any of those inputs is consistent with the description of what `InverseFunction` does. But of course, this behaviour of `InverseFunction` must have been designed for the more practical case where there are a finite (or countable) number of solutions, such as `InverseFunction[#^2 &][1]` or `InverseFunction[Sin][1]`.

Comment: The $\delta$-distribution is not a usual function so `DiracDelta[99/5]` makes no sense. Therefore, the input should be returned with an error message

Comment: @user64494 By that thinking, there should be no `DiracDelta` at all in Mathematica. But I'm pretty sure that when Dirac, a physicist, imagined this, he used intuition from normal functions, despite the fact that the idea could only be made mathematically precise using distribution theory.

Comment: I think the correct implementation of $\delta$-distribution in Mathematica should be done. The current `DiracDelta` command is a primitive implementation which is buggy.

Comment: Also by the same thinking, there should be no `Infinity` in Mathematica, or in any floating point representation standards, because, of course, `Infinity` is not a number and `1/0` is just nonsense. The countless programs that make use of this value should all be thrown out and considered buggy, along with any CPU implementing [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).